# how to run bash from python on windows?

Tags: python

I am trying to run commands from a python program.

I am not window command prompt person

I have import

```
import subprocess
```

Now, I am trying to command like grep, sed from python.
before I go little deep on command, I wanted to test ls -l command from python but the test case isn't working out

```
p = subprocess.run(["C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe", "ls", "-l"],capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout.decode())
```

I am getting error

```
Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 88556-88557: character maps to <undefined>
```

when I used this command

```
 p = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], shell=True, capture_output=True)
 print(p.stdout.decode())
```

I am getting the same error

Comment: those two code snippets are the same. did you mean to post two different ones?

Comment: sorry, I just edited the second one

Comment: try `decode("utf-8")`, this looks like an encoding issue

Comment: To pass a literal argv through, consider something like `['bash', '-c', '"$@"', 'ls', '-l']` -- though obvs., you do need to fix the character encoding issues. `bash ls -l`, which is what your code is effectively running, is not itself valid; `bash -c 'ls -l'` is, but trying to programmatically generate shell commands with arbitrary data is prone to security bugs and generally bad practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, swaggy, it's not working out. (it took forever to restart my laptop)

Comment: *shrug*. I live in the UNIX world; if I had a Windows dev system to test an answer on, I'd be writing an answer, not some comments. :)

Comment: Which version of Python? 2 or 3?